# Cannot access element in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do Inventory checking with using ajax post method and return with some array value. My `response` is okay, but I cannot access the array value of my `response`. I'm using `response[0]` and `response[1]["OptionKey"]` but it doesn't show anything.

response

```
[6,{"OptionKey":"215,221,224"}]
```

javascript

```
function InventoryChecking(LineOptionData) {
    var ItemID = $("#tiItemID").val();
    var OptVal = LineOptionData;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: '<?= site_url() ?>item/InventoryChecking',
        data: "ItemID=" + ItemID + "&OptVal=" + OptVal + "&From=" + From,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (From === "mytray") {
                $("#ItemBalance").text(response[0]);
            } else {
                $("#ItemBalance").text(response);
            }
            qty = $("#quantity").val();

            if (From === "mytray" && response[0] - qty === -qty && BaseLineOptionData === response[1]["OptionKey"]) {
                $("#btnAddToTray").attr("disabled", false);
            } else if ((response - qty) < 0) {
                // if( (response-qty)<0 ) {   
                if (response <= 0) {
                    $("#ItemBalance").text(0); //Show 0 instead of negative
                }
                if (ItemStockCheck == 0) {
                    $("#btnAddToTray").attr("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $("#btnAddToTray").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            } else {
                $("#btnAddToTray").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PHP to respond

```
if ($From === "mytray") {
   $array = [$reserved,$CombineOptID];
   echo json_encode($array); 
}
```

Comment: What are you getting in your response object ?

Comment: this is i get from my response [6,{"OptionKey":"215,221,224"}]

Comment: Your response may be coming back as text, not JSON. You might have to do `var obj = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: @jwatts1980. yeah you're correct. My response is as text.

Answer (score 0):

Based on jwatts1980 comment, my response is in string. To fix this I need to change my response to Javascript object.

`var obj = JSON.parse(response);`